# Java logging framework that guarantees log rotation at midnight

Tags: java, logging

I'm looking for a way to rotate a log file at midnight with the added requirement that regardless of what gets written in the log, the roll over time MUST be respected (the functional equivalent would be the *nix *logrotate* program).

All implementations I've looked at (log4j, logback) require a logging event as a trigger for a log rotation (the first log event *after* 00:00 triggers the rotation). This means there is no guarantee that logs are rotated at a given time (as the required trigger event might arrive hours later).

Is there a logging framework that guarantees log rotation at a given time?

Comment: did you ever solve this problem?

Comment: I did not find a proper solution - I used a dummy log event.

Answer (score 1):

If it is so, you can use CronTrigger to trigger a simple java class to do a dummy log at midnight everyday.

Assuming your code is on springframework, you can take the below configuration as a reference.

```
<bean id="logRotateAlert" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean">
  <property name="jobClass">
    <value>xxx.xxx.LogRotateAlert</value>
  </property>
</bean>
<bean id="cronTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
  <property name="jobDetail" ref="logRotateAlert"/>
  <property name="cronExpression" value="0 0 0 * * ?"/>
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
  <property name="triggers">
    <list>
      <ref bean="cronTrigger"/>
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the dummy log event is exactly what I'm trying to avoid.